# Imported jsp project giving error SEVERE: A child container failed during start

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jsp-tags

I imported the war file for jsp project into Eclipse. When running the project it gives giving following error. How to resolve this?

I have tried to run a test jsp project with tomcat it works. But this imported project has some issues.
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@42bc14c1]

Following is the project structure.

[image]
[image]

```
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version name:   Apache Tomcat/9.0.73
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Feb 27 2023 15:33:40 UTC
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version number: 9.0.73.0
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 11
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             D:\eclipse-jee-2023-03-R-win32-x86_64\eclipse\plugins\org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.win32.x86_64_17.0.6.v20230204-1729\jre
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           17.0.6+10
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Eclipse Adoptium
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\TomcatServer\apache-tomcat-9.0.73-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.73
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\TomcatServer\apache-tomcat-9.0.73-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.73
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\TomcatServer\apache-tomcat-9.0.73-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.73
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\TomcatServer\apache-tomcat-9.0.73-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.73
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\TomcatServer\apache-tomcat-9.0.73-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.73\wtpwebapps
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.io=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.base/java.util.concurrent=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: --add-opens=java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport=ALL-UNNAMED
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -XX:+ShowCodeDetailsInExceptionMessages
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: Loaded Apache Tomcat Native library [1.2.36] using APR version [1.7.2].
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true], UDS [true].
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: APR/OpenSSL configuration: useAprConnector [false], useOpenSSL [true]
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:50 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized [OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023]
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:51 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:51 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Server initialization in [1048] milliseconds
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:51 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.73]
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@42bc14c1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@42bc14c1]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [D:\TomcatServer\apache-tomcat-9.0.73-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.73\wtpwebapps\Sams5324_3] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:707)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 30 more

Mar 24, 2023 1:35:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
SEVERE: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:878)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@42bc14c1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:878)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@42bc14c1]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [D:\TomcatServer\apache-tomcat-9.0.73-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.73\wtpwebapps\Sams5324_3] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:707)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 30 more

Mar 24, 2023 1:35:52 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
SEVERE: The required Server component failed to start so Tomcat is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:249)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:428)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:772)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:347)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:478)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:878)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:890)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:795)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@42bc14c1]
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(FutureTask.java:122)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:878)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot@42bc14c1]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.resourcesStart(StandardContext.java:4606)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:4739)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1332)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1322)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:145)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:871)
    ... 21 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The main resource set specified [D:\TomcatServer\apache-tomcat-9.0.73-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-9.0.73\wtpwebapps\Sams5324_3] is not valid
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.createMainResourceSet(StandardRoot.java:749)
    at org.apache.catalina.webresources.StandardRoot.startInternal(StandardRoot.java:707)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    ... 30 more

Mar 24, 2023 1:35:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:52 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service [Catalina]
Mar 24, 2023 1:35:52 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it by removing projects from the tomcat server in the Eclipse server section. Readded the required project and it ran successfully.